# MVC3 Intranet Application / IIS Express Not Reading Site.css

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis, intranet

I first created an MVC3 Intranet web application in Visual Studio 2010 Professional.

It worked just fine.

I then right-clicked on the application and chose "Use IIS Express..."
I also edited the application properties and disabled Anonymous Authentication but enabled Windows Authentication.

Nothing more. This is a bare-bones, default skeleton of an application that I want to start from.

Now when I run, I first get a pop-up window to login with my username and password. This is just as I expect. However, when I log in, the "Home" and "About" pages are not formatted correctly. It looks like IIS Express isn't reading my Site.css file.

How do I fix this?

Thanks,
- Paul

Comment: is the login prompt looks like part of windows auth (dialog box) or part of the web app?  it sounds like you need to work out permissions that the iis express runs under and account's ability to the static content.  if you switch back to cassini, does it work ok?

Answer (score 1):

The default links for the style sheets typically use the ../../ directory navigation. When you're on a real webserver, those links typically fail 'cause now you're in a different folder setup. An easy way to correct them is to use:

```
<link href="<%: Url.Content("~/Content/style.css") %>" 
      rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

The url.content part will rebase the links to the current directory and will link up it's content correctly.

Hope this helps some, and good luck on your project.

Comment: Chris:Thanks. This was helpful